# How to save scrolling position of recyclerview list by updating RecyclerViewAdapter per second

Tags: android-recyclerview

(notifyDataSetChanged in onBindViewHolder is not working to update whole list per second . So I have updated list by creating new adapter per second time interval .)

To update counter and other chat data I have executed below lines periodically per second. It is getting scrolled up again and again.
So how to save scrollposition of the list even if it is updated periodically.

```
mAdapter = new ChatInfoRecyclerViewAdapter(getDataSet1());
                //mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```